Achieving hierarchy and categorization in custom activities in WPF/WWF
I am attempting to build a custom activity (workflow foundation) using designers and leveraging codeactivity.
I notice that the Activities panel to the left populates according to the project namespace with dot notation.
Labs.Algorithm.Activities.SoundBased namespace will look like below (note that this project is created when a solution is being created as well)
Hierarchy is seen here
I have potential number of activities that need to be categorized in different categories (SoundBased, TokenBased etc) but the package ID that is generated and the common namespace Labs.Algorithm.Activities. should remain the same.
Is there a way to achieve the categorization?
What I have tried:

Nested namespaces. (Designer xaml seems to not like it, I am unable to bind ModelItems)
Different projects with namespaces (the hierarchy is not affected at all, goes with the package ID)
Bundled different packages together into a wrapper package (but the execute method being protected wasted my time)
Used Category attribute for the class, still it remains unaffected.

Any help pointing the right direction would be really appreciated..
